# Applet - 'java.lang.NullPointerException: null pData' when browser closed

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception

I have one user who gets an error message when he closes his browser. This only happens when he has visited a page which contains my applet. It seems to have been registered as a bug at Sun but that was many years ago. He is using Java 1.6 and IE7.

Has anyone seen this before and know a solution or work-around?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null pData
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.hide(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.removeNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.removeAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.viewer.frame.IExplorerEmbeddedFrame.windowClosed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**UPDATE** The user removed Google Desktop and the problem has not occured since. So there you go... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to get that error a lot for just about every applet that was loaded in the browser.  I never figured out *how*, but Google Desktop was breaking java in some way.  After uninstalling google desktop the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a solution but I know a prevention of this problem.
If javascript is enabled in your web browser then place this code in a script tag inside your head tag of the html file from which applet is opened:

```
<SCRIPT language = "JavaScript">
    window.onunload = function() { document.body.innerHTML = ""; } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had them try 1.6u10?  It was released last week, and supposedly fixes a number of applet issues.  Otherwise, what build of 1.6 are they using?